Meaning of 打って変わって
From afterword of Kakegurui volume 1,

I have doubts the meaning of 打って変わって here. Does it mean something along the lines of "in contrast with the previous game, which is luck-based"? Maybe it is an adverb for 物を言う and 打って変わって技量が物を言う means "difference in skill can greatly impact the game"?

Your first interpretation is correct. This 打って変わって is "Conversely" or "Quite differently from the previous game". 打って変わって cannot modify a noun, so "difference in skill" is not a possible interpretation.
